# How to update an existing nodejs application

Tags: node.js, pm2

**I am not a Node.js developer**, but I know basic HTML and Linux. I know how to stop and start nodejs applications via **pm2**. 
I was tasked to update the title for our webpage (seems like an easy task), but after modifying it directly on the server and restarting the application, the changes I made are not showing. Here is what I did:

1. cd /project
2. vi source.js, *edit file*, then *:wq* to save changes
3. pm2 stop web
4. pm2 start web

My changes is not showing. What did I miss? Our server is CentOS 7.

Comment: I even delete contents of footers( the <p> tag) in footer.vue, restart the application but my changes are not showing.

Comment: I have a success in updating the application, but I have to uninstall and reinstall nodejs, then start again the application for the changes to take effect.. I believe I am just missing something here..